Sigma algebra generated by conditional expectation on a random variable
Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ and two random variables $X,Y:(\Omega,\mathcal{A})\mapsto(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, suppose $X$ and $Y$ satisfy $X = \mathbb{E}[Y|X]$, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s., then we know that, for any set $B\in\sigma(X)$, it holds that
$\int_B X d\mathbb{P} = \int_B Y d\mathbb{P}.$ I wonder whether this allows us to say anything about the relationship between $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$? In particualr, do we have $\sigma(X)\subset\sigma(Y)$? Intuitively I think this is is incorrect, but I cannot prove it formally. Any suggestions or counter-examples would be highly appreciated.
My thoughts: we have $B\subset Y^{-1}(Y(B))\in\sigma(Y)$, but if $\sigma(X)\subset\sigma(Y)$, we need to show that for each $B$, $Y^{-1}(Y(B))\in\sigma(X)$, which does not seem to be guaranteed, as the pre-image of $Y(B)$ can map to sets on $\Omega$ that do not belong to $\sigma(X)$.

The following property of sigma field may help you better understand this question: $\sigma(X)\subset \sigma(Y)$ is equivalent to $X$ is measurable with respect to Y. It is also equivalent to $X$ can be written as $f(Y)$, where $f$ is a borel measurable function.
To construct a counter-example, let $X$ and $Z$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables. $Y=X+Z$. Then $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=X$. However, $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{var}(Y)}Y\neq X$, which implies that $X$ is not measurable with respect to $Y$.
